# Recording button states

Tags: android, android-xml

I'm creating recording button and I need these states, but I don't know how to implement them with the xml. I've tried activated, selected, and pressed states but these are not getting the job done. I have all the drawables created already but the states are screwing me up.

**States I need the recording button to do:**

**State 1.** default Image of button (initial state)

**State 2.** Set drawable of button when the button is in the process of being pressed down

**State 3.** Set drawable of button after it has been pressed (after pressed down) and we are now in recording mode

**State 4.** After the button is clicked again return back to initial state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/record_button_default_state" />

<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/record_button_recording" />

<item
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/record_button_default_state" />

<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/record_button_pressed_state" />
```

**OnClickListener()**

```
case R.id.record_button:
        if (mr.getState() == ExtAudioRecorder.State.READY){
            mr.start();
            record_button.setSelected(true);

        }
        else if(mr.getState() == ExtAudioRecorder.State.RECORDING){
            mr.stop();
            mr.release();

            record_button.setSelected(false);

            setMediaPlayerPathAndPrepare();


        }
        break;
```

Comment: Are you aiming for something similar as described on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground ?

Comment: @Chilledrat yeah, sorry I added some code that shows what I've been trying. I don't fully understand all of the STATE terminology, but I'm not sure that it is possible with the states they give or if I have to do something a little more custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to be using the [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) control.**

Here's the **selector** code you'll need to call up:

*(I've labelled the drawables to the states they correspond to, as per your post).*

*tb_selector.xml*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/state4"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/state2"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/state3"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/state1" />
</selector>
```

**Reason for the default drawable being declared last:** [Android applies the first item in the state list that matches the current state of the object. So, if the first item in the list contains none of the state attributes above, then it is applied every time, which is why your default value should always be last (as demonstrated in the following example).](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

**Sample [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) XML:**

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="Vibrate on"
    android:textOff="Vibrate off"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked" 
    android:background="@drawable/tb_selector" />
```

**Sample [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) click event:**

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        // Enable vibrate
    } else {
        // Disable vibrate
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, so if I do it this way do I the toggle checked in the onClick?

Comment: @JordanHochstetler I've updated my answer with raw `ToggleButton` XML & an `onToggleClicked` event.

Comment: is that a custom method onToggleClicked or is it a listener or ToggleButtons cuz I didnt see the listener.

Comment: @JordanHochstetler Please view the referenced documents, I've linked the Android Docs for ToggleButton.

Comment: Yup, works great, BUT there is an ON and OFF text in front of my image. Do you know how to turn that off?

Comment: Solved it... change your textOn and textOff fields to empty string

Answer (score 0):

The OS handles the selected state of a button based on whether it is being pressed/clicked or not.  You can't set that in code.  If you want to change the button while something is happening, you must do it in code:

```
case R.id.record_button:
    if (mr.getState() == ExtAudioRecorder.State.READY){
        mr.start();
        record_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_button_recording);
    }
    else if(mr.getState() == ExtAudioRecorder.State.RECORDING){
        mr.stop();
        mr.release();

        record_button.setImageResource(R.drawable.record_button_default_state);

        setMediaPlayerPathAndPrepare();
    }
```